# Clearances issues during routing

Tags: pcb-design, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, pcb-layers

I am designing a 4-layer PCB in Altium, and I have defined my clearance rules for my high-voltage board (100 V) in the rules section, but the Altium software has a default clearance rule of minimum 0.3 mm between everything which is not allowing me to introduce some vias or polygons in the layers.

What should be done? Is it fine to introduce polygon nets in the bottom layer? What I have read is that in a 4-layer board the 2nd layer should be the GND plane and the 3rd layer should be the power plane.

P.S.: It is a double pulse test circuit setup having 2 grounds: microcontroller ground and HV ground. An isolated gate driver is being used.

Comment: How crowded is it of you can't fit vias? How large vias are you using?